# C++ Try Catch inside loop

Tags: c++, while-loop, try-catch, control-flow

I have this C++ program with the following general structure

```
1st while (condition A == true)
  //some code for 1st loop

  2nd while (condition B == true)
    //some code for 2nd loop
    try
      //some code for try
    catch
      //condition B == false (supposed to leave 2nd loop and go back to first loop)
```

I want it to get out of 2nd loop when there's an exception and go back to 1st loop until condition B is tue again. As described above it doesn't work as I expect. What seems to be happening is that code gets stuck in `catch` and never leaves it.

How can I arrange it to make it work as I need?

Note: condition A is never false.

Comment: When you say `condition B == false`, do you mean that you are setting condition B to false inside the catch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add the break keyword to the catch

Also notice that you have b == false;
That is checking that b is equal to false, not setting b = false.

Comment: Thank you! And indeed, I made a double mistake with `condition == B` inside catch (here and in the code itself). Thanks for pointing that out too. This show I need to read about break and continue again. I was trying continue but didn't even think about break (thought that it would stop program execution completely).

Comment: break will break out of the current for loop.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

```
bool flag1 = true, flag2 = true;
while (flag1)
{
  // some work so that flag2 == true
  while (flag2)
  {
    try
    {

    }
    catch (...) // any exception happens
    {
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1st while (condition A == true) 
  //some code for 1st loop 

  2nd while (condition B == true) 
    //some code for 2nd loop 
    try 
      //some code for try 
    catch 
    {
      //condition B == false (supposed to leave 2nd loop and go back to first loop) 
      break ;
    }
```

Notice: Please do not use, even in examples, things like `condition A == true`. It is better to use `while (condition  A)`.

Comment: I think I will disagree here.  I think it is totally fine to include ==true.  It makes it more explicit and can at times be more readable.  It is just a matter of coding conventions and styles.  Personally, I do not include them, but I don't mind seeing them from other people.

Comment: No problem. I am not following my style, though, but what the coding gurus were teaching my at the university. I am passing this knowledge only.

Answer (score 0):

You can call break within the catch block to escape the second loop:

```
void foo(void) {
    bool A(true);
    while (A) {
        bool B(doSomething());
        while (B) {
            try {
                B = doSomethingElseThatMayThrow();
            } catch (...) {
                break;
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Alternatively, you could place the second loop inside the try block:

```
void foo(void) {
    bool A(true);
    while (A) {
        bool B(doSomething());
        try { 
            while (B) {
                B = doSomethingElseThatMayThrow();
            }
        } catch (...) {}
    }
}
```