# C++ Exception handling Inside loop not working

Tags: c++, try-catch

**Related question:**

I found a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222947/c-try-catch-inside-loop) question already posted here on stackoverflow but for some reason the answer doesn't work in my case.

**My question:**

I am not able to get out of the loop in the following code when I enter a non-integer value.

```
int main(){
  int num;
  do {
      cout << endl << "\tEnter number (enter anything other than a number to exit): ";
      try{
          cin >> num;
      }catch(...){
          break; // I also tried "return 1;", "exit(1);" with no success 
      }
  }while(1);
  return 0;
}
```

Please note that I am not an expert in c++.

Comment: `std::cin` won't throw exceptions on failure.

Comment: why ? In other programming languages like `python` that is not a problem

Comment: Mostly because C++ is not Python.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen While true, `cin` can actually be configured to throw, it is just not turned on by default since throwing is expensive.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen In c++ exceptions are usually reserved for exceptional situations due to their relative cost. It's easy to argue that bad user input is not exceptional, it's typical. Though if you *want* throwing `cin` see [`std::basic_ios::exceptions`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions).

Comment: guys I am getting an error: `numeric_limits is not a member of 'std'`